# Incorrect horizontal scrolling by clicking on links to hash-anchors in Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, anchor, css-position, horizontal-scrolling

In one of my projects i encounter a strange behavior in Google Chrome (v.18.0.1025.168 m).

In Firefox, IE, Opera works everything fine, but in Chrome there is an incorrect horizontal scrolling by clicking on links to hash-anchors.
Vertical scrolling works ok, but horizontal is very bad.

Sometime the requested div is displayed well, but in most cases the div-blocks are left or right outside the visual scope.

You can reproduce this with the following code.
By clicking  on the top-lef-fixed menu: top, left, right, moreright, right for example.

I am not sure if this is a Chrome-Bug or i am overlook something?! What do you mean?
Is there a known workaround?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Google-Chrome don't follows anchors properly - incorrect horizontal scrolling</title>
<style type="text/css">
body
{
    min-width: 700px;
    overflow: auto;
}

div
{
    position: absolute;
    width: 400px;
    height: 300px;
    z-index: 1;
    padding-left:160px;
}

#top
{
    border: 1px solid black;
    top:0px;
    left: 400px;
    background: gray;
}

#left
{
    border: 1px solid blue;
    left:0px;
    top: 400px;
    background:#00d;
}

#right
{
    border: 1px solid orange;
    left:800px;
    top: 800px;
    background: yellow;
}
#moreright
{
    border: 1px solid red;
    left:1600px;
    top: 1500px;
    background:#d00;
}

div#fixedmenu
{
    position: fixed;
    top:0;
    left: 0;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    background: #ddd;
    border: 1px solid gray;
    z-index: 2;
    margin: 0;
    padding:0;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="top" >top</div>
<div id="left">left</div>
<div id="right">right</div>
<div id="moreright">moreright</div>

<div id="fixedmenu">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#top">top</a></li>
        <li><a href="#left">left</a></li>
        <li><a href="#right">right</a></li>
        <li><a href="#moreright">moreright</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Just a nit-pick, the 'hash' tag for stack overflow generally refers to the computer science concept of hash functions http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function You're right on with the 'anchor' tag :-)

Comment: I just tried this on JSFiddle with chrome, and it seems to be related to which direction the horizontal scroll is coming from. The #left and #moreright anchors pin the scroll bar to either side of the window, so it doesn't move the scroll bar at all when moving to the #right anchor, which is noticeably different from the behavior i see in firefox 3.6. FF makes an effort to always put the scroll bar such that the whole div is visible. Take a look and let me know what if that's what you're seeing: http://jsfiddle.net/jBf3y/

Comment: Yes, this is what i am talking about. The outgoing horizontal position impacts the horizontal landing position. It is important by testing to have the same sequence of clicks, in order to get the same result.The document.documentElement.clientWidth /window.innerWidth are important factors also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each link add onclick, who call a Javascript Jump-Function::

```
<a href="#moreright" onclick="jump('moreright')">moreright</a>
```

JS:

```
function jump(element_id)
{
        var d = document.getElementById(element_id);

        var gx = d.offsetLeft;
        var e = d;
        if (d.offsetParent) while (e = e.offsetParent) gx += e.offsetLeft;

        var gy = d.offsetTop;
        var e = d;
        if (d.offsetParent) while (e = e.offsetParent) gy += e.offsetTop;

        window.scrollTo(gx,gy);

}
```

.. and horizontal scrolling in Chrome works ..

Answer (score 0):

Well it is definitely a difference in behavior between browsers, but I would stop short of calling it a bug. The right place to go to sort that out would be [the Chrome Support Forums](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!forum/chrome), in my opinion.

As for a work around, there are a lot of solutions, the most obvious of which is to just stick to vertical scrolling. The pertinent question to ask yourself is "what functionality am I trying to achieve and what compromises am I willing to accept?"

From the implementation you posted, I would assume you're looking for something to put more information on a single page load and quickly flip between different subsections. Do you really need to scroll horizontally? Is there some reason you're not using a javascript plugin? [Jquery Tabs](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/) comes to mind, as does [Jquery Accordion](http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/). There are probably a lot of other libraries that accomplish the same thing.

If there are other restrictions you're working with, feel free to post them and we can brainstorm some solutions.

Comment: Thank you Patrick for your suggestion. I have already reported this as bug. But it will be fixed sometime in future. I need solution now. I wouldn't change the page concept. It should be a big "map"-like page. I will handle the scrolling via javascript. A Solution is on the way...

Comment: I hadn't thought of a page of continous information. That is a pretty ingenious way for make an accessible, navigable map. I wonder if anyone else has implemented anything for it. Best of luck and do post if you find a js implementation!